# Datagridview form always open with row in selected state

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I have two forms: `frmMain` and `frmProduct`

In the main form `frmMain`, I have a `Datagridview1` and the buttons: `tsbInsert_click`, `tsbAlter_click` and `tsbConsult_click`.

When I open the main form `frmMain`, there is still no row in the `Datagridview1` and when I click on any of the `tsbAlter_click` or `tsbConsult_click` buttons, the code displays the message "Select a product", which is correct , because there is still no product created in the register.

When I click on the `tsbInsert_click` button, the code opens the `frmProduct` to insert a record in the register and then returns to the main form `frmMain`, which, in the line of the `Datagridview1`, shows the record that was included.

The problem is that when I include a record in the register, the `Datagridview1` ALWAYS returns with the state of the selected row, and the condition `If DGProducts.CurrentRow Is Nothing` is never true again ... so when I click on `tsbAlter_click` or `tsbConsult_click`, the "Select a product" message no longer appears and it should have since I didn't select any rows in `Datagridview1`.

`frmMain` Code:

```
Public Class frmMain

     Private Sub tsbInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbInsert.Click
         
         Using frm As New frmProduct("Insert", "")
             frm.ShowDialog()
             If frm.txtPrdCod.Text <> "" Then
                 DGProducts.Rows.Add(Campo(0), Campo(1), Campo(2))
             End If
         End Using

     End Sub

     Private Sub tsbAlter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbAlter.Click

         If DGProducts.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
             MessageBox.Show("Select a product")
             Exit Sub
         End If
        
         Dim codProd As String = DGProducts.CurrentRows.Cells("prdCod").Value

         Using frm As New frmProduct("Alter", codProd)
             frm.ShowDialog()
             With DGProducts.Rows(DGProds.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
                 .Cells("prdCod").Value = Field(0)
                 .Cells("prdName").Value = Field(1)
                 .Cells("prdManufac").Value = Field(2)
             End With
         End Using
     End Sub

     Private Sub DGProducts_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGProducts.CellEnter
         With DGProducts.Rows(DGProducts.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
              Campo(0) = .Cells("prdCod").Value
              Campo(1) = .Cells("prdName").Value
              Campo(2) = .Cells("prdManufac").Value
         End With
     End Sub
End Class
```

`frmProduct` code:

```
Public Class frmProduct

    Private Sub frmProduct_Load(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If _operation = "Alter" Then
                txtPrdCod.Text = Campo(0)
                txtPrdName.Text = Campo(1)
                txtManufct.Text = Campo(2)
        Else
                txtPrdCod.Text = ""
                txtPrdName.Text = ""
                txtManufct.Text = ""
        Enf If
    End Sub

    Dim _operation As String
    Dim _codProd As String


    Public Sub New(operation As String, codProd As String)
        InitializeComponent()

        Select Case operation
            Case "Insert"
                _operation = operation
            Case "Alter"
                _operation = operation
                _codProd = codProd
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid option!")
                Close()
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub tsbRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbRecord.Click
        Field(0) = txtPrdCod.Text
        Field(1) = txtPrdName.Text 
        Field(2) = txtManufct.Text 
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

How do I make it so that when I add a product to the register, `Datagridview1` DOES NOT return with the line in the SELECTED state and the message "Select a product" appears when I don't select a line from `Datagridview1`?

Comment: Could be a little wrong here but think your attempting to solve a problem of your own making by manipulating the data direct in the DataGridView.  You may find it an all-round better option to have something like a DataTable which you add/edit/remove rows from which is bound to your DVG

Comment: The current row and a selected row are NOT the same thing. The current row is the row that contains the caret. If the grid contains any rows at all. one of them MUST be the current row, so you should expect that `CurrentRow` will never be `Nothing`. A selected row is one that is highlighted and contained in the `SelectedRows` collection. If what you actually care about is a selected row then the current row is irrelevant. Unless there are no rows in the grid, there will always be one and only one current row. There may be zero, one or more selected rows. The current row may be selected or not.

Comment: @Hursey ??????... the only thing I wanted to know is how, after inserting the record, it gets written to the datagridview as not selected!! Because in the tests I did it is being recorded in datagridview1 as selected.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Okay. What I want is for the `tsbAlter_click` or `tsbConsult_click` buttons to be executed only when I select a line in datagridview1,... so what command should I put in `If DGProducts` that will check if I didn't select anything in datagridview1 to show the message "Select a record"?

Comment: Like I said, it's the `SelectedRows` collection that you're interested in so you need to test whether there are any items in that collection. How do you usually check whether there are any items in a collection?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I changed it to `If DGProds.SelectedRows.Count = 0`, but it didn't work because the `Count` value is set to 1 even though I haven't clicked on any line in datadridview1!... because the line created in datagridview1 is with `SelectedRows.Count` equal to 1 if I didn't even click on it in datagridview1?

Comment: If a row is selected by default and you don't want that, how about you unselect it?

Comment: @jmcilhinney the value of Datagridview1.SelectedRows.Count is 1... how do I change the value of Datagridview1.SelectedRows.Count to 0?

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for the help, I got it by including the command `DGProds.CurrentCell = Nothing` after command `DGProducts.Rows.Add` in code.

Answer (score 0):

The command `DGProducts.Rows.Add(Field(0), Field(1), Field(2))`, automatically changes the value `DGProducts.SelectedRows.Count` to 1, so I set `DGProducts.CurrentCell = Nothing` after command `DGProducts.Rows.Add` in code:

```
Private Sub tsbInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbInsert.Click
         
    Using frm As New frmProduct("Insert", "")
        frm.ShowDialog()
        If frm.txtPrdCod.Text <> "" Then
            DGProducts.Rows.Add(Campo(0), Campo(1), Campo(2))
            DGProducts.CurrentCell = Nothing
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```